# How to add a CSS transform or filter to an existing inline SVG transform or filter?

Tags: css, svg, filter, transform

Without knowing what the inline SVG transform or filter is, how can I apply extra transforms or filters to the same element using CSS?

Whatever I try, my CSS transform or filter overwrites the inline SVG transform/filter, instead of adding to it.

For example I have in my SVG:
`<circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100)">`

And then I try to scale this circle using a CSS transform, without removing its initial translate transform:

```
circle {
  transform: initial scale(0.5);
}
```

However, the original translate is replaced by the scale transform, they are not added.
The same problem applies to filters.

Comment: That is not part of the CSS semantics. You will need to apply them to a parent element.

Answer (score 1):

As @ccprog says. Wrap the element in a parent `<g>` element, and apply your transform or filter to that.

```
<g>
  <circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100)">
</g>

g {
  transform: scale(0.5);
}
```

However, be aware that may give a different result to what you are expecting.
The following two SVGs are not equivalent.

```
<g transform="scale(0.5)">
  <circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100)">
</g>

<g>
  <circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100) scale(0.5)">
</g>
```

You would need to modify the transform you apply to the group to get an equivalent result.

The equivalent of

```
<g>
  <circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100) scale(0.5)">
</g>
```

is either

```
<g transform="scale(0.5) translate(100,100)">
  <circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100)">
</g>
```

or

```
<g transform="translate(50,50) scale(0.5)">
  <circle r="50" transform="translate(100,100)" fill="blue"/>
</g>
```